# use the ordered field $\mathbb{R}$. For $|x−y|<0.01$ and $x,y\in(0,2),$ show that $|x^2−y^2|<0.04$ only use properties of absoulte values

Tags: calculus, real-numbers, absolute-value, ordered-fields

I Don't know how to start this question can someone please help me?
Use the ordered field $\mathbb{R}$. For $|x−y|<0.01$ and $x,y\in(0,2),$ show that $|x^2−y^2|<0.04$

Answer (score 2):

$$
|x^2-y^2|=|x-y| |x+y|<10^{-2}|x+y|\le10^{-2} (2+2)=0.04
$$